# Is thinlto's concurrency useful in a parallel build system?

Tags: build, linker, llvm, lto

I have a build system that is using the long standing LTO support in clang via the `-flto` flag.

The ThinLTO support added to LLVM (https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThinLTO.html) looks interesting, but I'm a little puzzled about the decision to launch `std::thread::hardware_concurrency` parallel processing threads in the context of a build system that already runs concurrent jobs.

If you have a build system that is already launching a thread per core and running a mix of compile and link jobs, does it still make sense for the linker to assume that it should use all cores, or even more than one?

Or does it make sense instead to reduce ThinLTOs background concurrency to 1 with the flags documented at https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThinLTO.html#controlling-backend-parallelism? Are there any advantages to ThinLTO over regular plain old LTO when the parallelism has been removed?

Comment: My understanding is that it solves the link-time bottleneck of the build process. My `ninja`-based compilations of translation units already run in parallel, as you mentioned, but then the link step is separate. That bottleneck of glueing the `.o` together still exists in "traditional" LTO, prior to running any whole program optimizations. That's where one of the main advantages lies, addressing scale and speed.

Comment: @compor - That makes sense for a link where you have lots of prerequisite compilation and then one final link step at the end. But what about the case where you have lots of compilations *and* lots of links, like unit test binaries. If you are running a build like that in parallel with thinlto, it seems to me that you could end up with $NUMCPU concurrent links each using $NUMCPU threads, which sounds like massive over-subscription.

Comment: That makes sense, but it's a bit hard (or even out of scope?) for the linker to accommodate this case since we are talking about different invocations that will produce different binaries (irrespective of LTO type). In that case, I think the responsibility falls back to the build tool which orchestrates all this per project.

Comment: @compor - For sure, up to the build system to make that call, and since I think the oversubscription argument is valid, I've added the necessary `'-Wl,-plugin-opt,jobs=1'` incantation to the build. But what I'm really curious about is whether doing so effectively entirely reduces the advantages of `-flto=thin` over plain old `-flto`. Or does ThinLTO do other things that still make it the right way to achieve LTO in modern toolchains. If it does do other things than bring parallelism to the table, what are those things? The ThinLTO docs don't speak much to that, instead focusing on concurrency.

Comment: @compor - Some further thoughts. As I took a closer look at the ThinLTO design, it appears that another facet is incremental behavior and caching. That sounds pretty compelling for interactive usage, so maybe there is still an upside to using thinlto for that case. But for a CI system that is doing clean builds on each commit, the caching may not be useful or desired. I wonder then, if you take out *both* the parallelism and the incremental behavior, is there anything left of value in `-flto=thin` over plain `-flto`. The research continues...

Comment: I haven't used ThinLTO's caching, but the incremental processing gains are significant (depending on the structure of the project). I think it's hard to give a clear answer due to the many components involved (you just added a CI :-). A case study and comparison of the approaches side-by-side might provide some hints. It's indeed interesting, as it's directly associated with sw engineering lifecycle stages, rate of s/w change, etc.

Answer (score 1):

ThinLTO actually can greatly improve build times for large projects, among its other benefits. The cache is not designed only for incremental builds - it's part and parcel for how the multi-threaded link stage works and is meant to speed symbol lookups. How helpful ThinLTO is for you with respect to shortening build times depends on your project and build system.

I found a very good video that goes over some details of the design for ThinLTO, its usecases, and some ways it has been implemented successfully:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p9nH2vZ2mNo&list=WL&index=51&t=2812s

The corresponding Google Research paper is also a very interesting (if heavy) read:

https://research.google/pubs/pub47584/

For a lighter and more casual take, this blog post was also helpful:

http://blog.llvm.org/2016/06/thinlto-scalable-and-incremental-lto.html